# Запрос на добавление и обновление при нажатии кнопки

Tags: sql, access, vba

Есть форма с данными, на ней 2 кнопки, одна ее закрывает а другая призвана отредактировать имеющиеся записи и добавить их в другую таблицу. Для этого был привинчен такой код:

```
Private Sub Кнопка18_Click()


    Dim SQL As String

    SQL = "UPDATE Main " & _
        "SET Статус = 'Статус' AND "INSERT INTO Main_History" & _




    DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```

В таком виде `SQL = "UPDATE Main " & _
    "SET Статус = 'Статус'"` запрос работает, а в вышеупомянутом - нет. Подскажите как правильно привинтить на кнопку запрос на обновление одной таблицы, и добавление\обновление этих данных в другой? И бонусный вопрос: как передать данные с выпадающего списка в одной форме в поле на другой форме?))

Comment: Вы где-то потеряли строчки после `INSERT INTO`

Comment: Бонусные вопросы задавайте в новом вопросе

Answer (score 2):

Например, так

```vb
Dim SQL As String

SQL = "UPDATE Main " & _
        "SET Статус = 'Статус'"

DoCmd.RunSQL SQL

SQL = "INSERT INTO Main_History " & _
        "VALUES ('Произошла смена статуса')" 

DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```

Но это не атомарно (если вторая команда закончится сбоем, то первая не откатится), а вам судя по всему нужна атомарность. Значит надо использовать транзакции.

Answer (score 1):

Странно бы было, если бы синтаксически ошибочный запрос

```
UPDATE table SET field = value AND literal (lost text)
```

вдруг взял бы да и заработал...

Хотя в именно приведённом фрагменте ошибка синтаксиса ещё на стадии VBA - о чем, кстати, говорит подсветка кода. Кавычки нужно считать тщательнее...

Comment: Честно говоря пока не понял но попробую сам разобраться, если что - отпишу, главное - есть направление куда копать

Comment: @4per Сделал, как у Вас написано, ругается, выдает ошибку неверный синтаксис "INSERT INTO Main_History ". Написал так:
SQL = "INSERT INTO Main_History " (Поле1, Поле2, Поле3)& _
        "VALUES (Поле1 = 'Поле1', и т.д.)"